# TLS 1.2 in mono on ubuntu

Tags: .net, mono, tls1.2

I have installed the latest version of mono 
mon -V gives me:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.8.0 (Stable 4.8.0.495/e4a3cf3 Wed Feb 22 18:30:58 UTC 2017)
```

From the release notes(http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.8.0/) it says I have to:

> To use it, you must set the environment variable MONO_TLS_PROVIDER to
>   the value “btls”, like this:

I have not done this.
I came across a way to check if using 1.2(http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Still-stuck-in-a-bad-place-with-TLS-1-2-support-td4669106.html)
When I run this  I get:

> TLS 1.2, the most modern version of the encryption

So my question is, Is it correct to say I do not need to do anything only install latest mono and default is 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to verify whether TLS 1.2 is working or not is to attempt to connect to TLS 1.2-only service.

```
wget -q https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/attachment.cgi?id=16785 -O Program.cs
mcs Program.cs /r:System.Net.Http.dll
mono Program.exe
```

And the result:

> Error while sending TLS Alert (Fatal:InternalError): System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer

Once again, with BTLS this time (no need to compile again):

```
export MONO_TLS_PROVIDER="btls"
mono Program.exe
```

The result:

> OK!

So as you can see, BTLS is not default yet. Yes, there are also other ways to determine this, such as looking into stacktrace of the calls, but this one is the easiest one, since it results in an exception if endpoint supports only TLS 1.2 and you attempt to connect with it using outdated TLS 1.0 or 1.1.

BTW, the code comes from my **[bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42805)**. The result above was done with Mono 4.9.1, it should be the same on 4.8.